# FirebaseUser - Android - Get Login Providers

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Can anyone help me find the `getloginproviders` problem

```
public String getLoginProvider() throws Exception {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null)
            return firebaseUser.getProviders().get(0);
        else
            throw new Exception("Couldn't getMessage the provider");
    }
```

**build output find this error**

```
error: cannot find symbol
            return firebaseUser.getProviders().get(0);
                               ^
  symbol:   method getProviders()
  location: variable firebaseUser of type FirebaseUser
```

I don't know why the symbol . I used went into error

I am new to this. Hopefully someone can help.

Thank you!

Comment: According to the [documentation for `com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser), this class has method `getProviderData()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the API documentation, [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) doesn't have a method called "getProviders".  Perhaps you meant to use [getProviderData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getProviderData())

Comment: Thanks bro, you solved my app.

I'm using getProviderData from the link you give to me.
thank you very much bro, you helped my app